# Python Interactive Brokers TWS Net Liquidity

Tags: python, python-3.x, tws

I'm trying to get my account net liquidity to store it in a variable but whenever I'm trying to get it like this:

```
self.reqAccountSummary(9003, "All", "$LEDGER:EUR")
```

I'm getting none.
Anyone know how to get the net liquidity? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm succeeded to get my need by this exmaple:

```
  def start(self):
        self.reqAccountSummary(9002, "All", "$LEDGER")
```

I have implemented the above function in the IB Api Class.